# 2 MySQL Insert Statements and only the first one runs

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched high and low and cannot find anything to fix this problem. apparently my first  insert statement runs fine and I can see the changes in the database. The second one fails to update the database even though the script completes. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
"INSERT INTO propertyInfo (
                                        districtNumber,
                                        primaryProperty,
                                        platBookPage,
                                        giftedDate,
                                        purchaseDate,
                                        retiredDate,
                                        yearBuilt,
                                        Affiliation,
                                        purchasePrice,
                                        primaryZone,
                                        primaryLandUse,
                                        propertyType,
                                        squareFootage,
                                        soldDate,
                                        soldPrice,
                                        lotSizeSqFt,
                                        iudb,
                                        zoningLandUse,
                                        enterpriseZone,
                                        zoningCode,
                                        florida,
                                        georgia,
                                        Description,
                                        Land,
                                        Development,
                                        acres,
                                        tax,
                                        Name,
                                        granter
                                    )
                            VALUES  (
                                        '$district_number',
                                        '$primary_property',
                                        '$plat_book_page',
                                        '$gifted_date',
                                        '$purchase_date',
                                        '$retired_date',
                                        '$year_built',
                                        '$affiliation',
                                        '$purchase_price',
                                        '$primary_zone',
                                        '$primary_land_use',
                                        '$property_type',
                                        '$square_footage',
                                        '$sold_date',
                                        '$sold_price',
                                        '$lot_size_sqft',
                                        '$iudb',
                                        '$zoning_land_use',
                                        '$enterprise_zone',
                                        '$zoning_code',
                                        '$florida',
                                        '$georgia',
                                        '$description',
                                        '$land',
                                        '$development',
                                        '$acres',
                                        '$tax',
                                        '$name',
                                        '$granter'
                                    )";

    $pinksql = "INSERT INTO address (`address`, `address2`, `city`, `state`, `zipCode`, `subDivision`) VALUES ('$address', '$address2', '$city', '$state', '$zip_code', '$sub_division')";
```

Comment: Which system do you use? PDO? MySQLi?

Comment: Did you test the raw query directly against the database (i.e. in PHPMyAdmin, CLI)? What's the result?

Comment: When I run it in PHPMyAdmin like this it works:

Comment: do you actually run both of the querys? with mysqli_query($con, $pinksql)?